# ffmpeg combine video streams into 1x4 collage

Tags: ffmpeg

Can anyone please help understand how to make correct `-filter_complex`
expression in `ffmpeg` to join 4 RTSP streams in a row collage 1x4? 
The complexity is that there is ONE input with 4 video streams inside.
`ffprobe` output:

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://MyStream':
  Metadata:
    title           : h264.sdp
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.024944, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 640x480, 27.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 640x480, 27.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 640x480, 27.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Stream #0:3: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 640x480, 27.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## A row of videos

You can use the [`hstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) (or [`vstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack)) video filter:

[image: overlay example]
<sub>In this example each color represents a separate video input or stream.</sub>

#### One input with four video streams (as in the question)

```
ffmpeg -i input \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:v:1][0:v:2][0:v:3]hstack=inputs=4[v]" \
-map "[v]" output.mp4
```

#### Four inputs with one video stream each

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i input3 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v]hstack=inputs=4[v]" \
-map "[v]" output.mp4
```

#### Same as above but with combined audio

Using the [`amerge`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i input3 -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v]hstack=inputs=4:shortest=1[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest output.mp4
```

## With padding or borders

You can add a border between each video with the [`pad`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) filter. This example will add 10 pixel padding between each video:

[image: overlay with padding]

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i input3 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw+10[v0]; \
 [1:v]pad=iw+10[v1]; \
 [2:v]pad=iw+10[v2]; \
 [0v][1v][2v][3:v]hstack=inputs=4[v]" \
-map "[v]" output.mp4
```